# ASP.NET site upgraded VS08 - VS10, and now compile-time errors do not show until I request the page at run-time

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I have an ASP.NET website that worked fine using and debugging in VS2008.  I went through the upgrade process opening the solution in VS2010.  I can run the site, but as I make changes in the app_code folder classes, they don't seem to commpile and warn me of compile-time errors.  As soon as I get to a point that calls the class, the errors show up.  Sounds JIT I guess, but this isn't how it was working in 08.  Is there an option that was changed in the upgrade process?  This is a large project, I really don't want to break something and not find out until some obscure page is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like a bit of an idiot, after asking the question, I went to my Configuration Manager and found that the web project was un-checked in the build column.  I still don't know why this would have changed from 08 to 10, but everything seems to be working now as it did on 08.